# LoadLibrary call from MVC application running in IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, interop, pinvoke

I'm having trouble executing this line of code in my MVC application:

```
IntPtr hModule = LoadLibrary(BondProbeSettings.AssemblyFilePath);
```

The problem is that `hModule` is always `0`.

If I run the same code with the same value for `BondProbeSettings.AssemblyFilePath` but from a console application instead of the MVC app `hModule` is non-zero.

Are there any security issues I need to consider?

The signature for LoadLibrary is:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
static extern IntPtr LoadLibrary(string lpFileName);
```

Answer (score 3):

Change the declaration to:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto), SetLastError = true)]
static extern IntPtr LoadLibrary(string lpFileName);
```

And your code to:

```
IntPtr hModule = LoadLibrary(BondProbeSettings.AssemblyFilePath);
if (hModule == IntPtr.Zero) throw new System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception();
```

Now you'll know why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Yep you need to run the site assembly in full trust. I haven't configured this myself but I reckon you need:

- to GAC the dll (meaning it has to be strongnamed)
- to perhaps configure the application pool in IIS (assuming IIS) to allow full trust (?)

I'm on linux so I can't really help you with screenshots right now